# ..msw\bitmap.cpp(842): assert ""image.IsOk()"" failed in wxBitMap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image [C++][wxWidgets 3.1.3]

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The following code compiles and runs fine under Linux:

https://i.postimg.cc/B6PPn01C/Screenshot-20200320-184650.png

```
staticboxsizer_Logo = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL, Panel1, wxEmptyString);
    staticbitmap_logo = new wxStaticBitmap(Panel1, ID_STATICBITMAP2, wxBitmap(wxImage(_T("C:\Logo_0.png"))), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICBITMAP2"));
    staticboxsizer_Logo->Add(staticbitmap_logo, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);[/code]
```

Under Windows it compiles fine too, however when I run the .exe I get the following error:

```
C:\wxWidgets\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(842): assert ""image.IsOk()"" failed in wxBitMap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image
```

What can I do so the logo (265x46 px) also shows fine under Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a valid file path.

`"/mnt/data/VMware/VM-Shared/Logo_0.png"` is not a valid path under `Windows`.

Comment: That path is from the Linux version, however on Windows I used a correct Windows path, the path is no the problem here

Comment: @var_null, is wxImage object successfully created? Is `wxBitmap.IsOk()` function returns success?

Comment: Had to use "C:\\Logo_0.png" instead of "C:\Logo_0.png", double backslashes. Problem solved.